# Sleep mode of Dell Precision 3581 and power consumption

Tags: laptop, energy-efficient

I have the habit of using "suspend" mode with my laptop in order to keep my session open in its current state.

I find myself now with a Dell Precision 3581 which doesn't seem to allow either "deep" Suspend-To-RAM. Using the shallow "s2idle" suspend mode is a no go, as it consumes 3 W power and thus empties the battery within hours. It seems that this is a feature of the series, since a Precision 3561 also has only "s2idle" ability.

I believe this SE is adapted although (unfortunately) I have already bought this laptop, which was the only one in the price range on my company's catalogue, since in order to decide whether this is an issue with my OS (Debian, the other Dell having an Unbuntu OS) or whether hardware recommenders can confirm that this is a limitation of this laptop series. Dell support doesn't seem to know or want to tell me.

My current workaround is to use "hibernate", I have [created a large swap partition for this.](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/how-to-create-swap-partition-in-linux.html)

So: is it really a hardware/bios limitation, and if so, can one know before buying for other laptop series or brands whether energy-efficient sleep/hibernation modes will be available?