# Sleep mode of HP Elite x360 and power consumption

Tags: laptop, energy-efficient

**EDIT** : I managed to have contact with an HP sales advisor, but they confused my question as to whether "suspend-to-disk" (hibernate) is available. Most of the ressources I find about "deep suspend-to-RAM" are linux oriented... how can I phrase unambiguously my question in terms of hardware? Eg does deep suspend mode correspond to some ISO standard??

I have the habit of using "suspend" mode with my laptop in order to keep my session open in its current state.

Before buying this HP Elite computer, I'd like to be certain that it supports a suspend-to-RAM mode which is low in power consumption. Indeed I've been very upset by [a Dell computer series that doesn't](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18527/sleep-mode-of-dell-precision-3581-and-power-consumption)

Could anyone with a HP Elite x360 tell me:

- whether the computer supports "deep" sleep mode (under windows: `powercfg /a`, under linux: give the output of `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`)
- or monitor how much power it consumes per hour when suspended (under linux, you can use `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep energy:` to have the current battery charge, you can issue this before/after a suspend of known duration)

Comment: Since I don't own an HP Elite x360 (either the 830 or 1040), I'm reliant on what I can find online. I tried checking linux-hardware.org and comparing the probes they have for the [HP 830](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=d462837d11), [HP 1040](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f84212c870), and [Dell Precision 3581](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2e960d89db); unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be something that's collected by their probes (the closest, Upower, seems to just say the current critical action, and shows HybridSleep for both teh 830 and 3581.)

Comment: I'd probably recommend just buying one from a vendor with free returns, and returning it if it doesn't work out, or buying a laptop with known/reputable support, such as a [Framework](https://frame.work/), [System76](https://system76.com/), or [even a modified Chromebook with updated Coreboot.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HFIQi835wY)